# Search Query Rules not showing in Central Admin

Tags: search, 2016, central-administration, sharepoint-search, query

I have created few Search Query Rules from different site collections.

I was trying to edit them from CA and I cant see none of them. Any reason?

[image]

Comment: which version of SharePoint you are using?

Comment: 2016, I just realized if you create a Query Rules at site collection level you cant see them in CA. The problem I have is for some reason I cant access my search query rules from site collection. I get attached error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Security Update kb4486677 will fix this issue.
An error occurs when you try to access the "Result Sources," "Query Rules," "Search Result Sources," or "Search Query Rules" page from the Search Settings section of Site Settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the search query rules at different levels in a SharePoint Server farm.

Site collection search query rules can be managed at Site collection by site collection administrator.

To manage query rules for a site collection:

1. Verify that the user account that performs this procedure is a **site collection administrator**.
2. On the **Settings** menu for the site collection, click Site Settings.
3. On the **Site Settings** page, in the **Site Collection Administration** section, click **Search Query Rules**.

**official documentations**:

1. [Manage query rules in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/manage-query-rules)
2. [Manage query rules in SharePoint Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-query-rules)

Comment: that's where I am having the problem, I cant access the Search Query Rules from Site collection.

Comment: Are you a site collection administrator for this site collection? If Yes, you need to check the ULS log for corresponding correlation ID and get more details about the error. If No, ask other site collection administrator to grant to you the permissions.

Comment: I am the site collection admin. I have created another site collection under same webApp and I can access to the Query Rules on the new site collection.

Comment: Please check the ULS log for corresponding correlation ID and add the errors you are getting to your question. that will be helpful to answer your question.

Comment: Entering Monitored Scope (Cobalt.CellStorageProcessor.HandleQueryChanges.OnExecute). Parent=Cobalt.RequestProcessor.ExecuteRequest